# What happened to git local changes on new version of IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I updated IntelliJ and now the Git screen doesn't seem to have the *local changes* tab I allways used to do commits to my server. Am I missing it? Did I accidentally do some configuration that blew it away?

[image]

Googled, but can't even find the old screen on the JetBrains help site, so it definitely looks removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now, it looks like IntelliJ has a commit window (shortcut 0) that handles the commits. This has the local changes and a place for your commit message instead of the old dialogs.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You may disable "Use non-modal commit interface" option in "Settings/Preferences | Version Control | Commit" to revert to old layout.